# Spring Batch Java Config @EnableBatchProcessing Annotation Error

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-batch

I'm using Spring Batch 2.2 with Spring 3. I'm trying to configure my job with Java config instead of the usual XML Config. Below is my AppConfig class :

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class AppConfig {

    @Autowired private JobBuilderFactory jobs;
    @Autowired private StepBuilderFactory steps;
    private Tasklet simpleTasklet = new SimpleTasklet();

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobs.get("myJob").start(step1(simpleTasklet)).build();
    }

    @Bean protected Step step1(Tasklet tasklet) {
        return steps.get("step1").tasklet(tasklet).build();
    }

}
```

And runs it using this class below :

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher)context.getBean("jobLauncher");
        Job job = (Job) context.getBean("myJob");
        try{
            JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
            System.out.println("Exit status : " + execution.getStatus());
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

}
```

It yields this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.BatchConfigurationSelector was imported as a @Configuration class but was not actually annotated with @Configuration. Annotate the class or do not attempt to process it.
Offending resource: class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/BatchConfigurationSelector.class]
```

and the error stack points at this line :

```
ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
```

What am I doing wrong? Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the import for your @Configuration is wrong.  It should be...

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
```

If it's not this I'd recommend using Spring Boot to start the application so you can be certain that it's wiring correctly.

Comment: I went the Spring Boot route for minimal headache, but later I abandoned both annotation and Spring Boot altogether and opt for the usual XML config. It's less customizable but there's also less complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to annotate your App Class:

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class App {
...
```

1st for finding your Configuration in preprocessing Beans and 2nd for critical Beans needed by your Batch Processing. 
In your Line:

```
Job job = (Job) context.getBean("myJob");
```

please write here:

```
Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
```

because its Autowiring by Type.

Comment: I did what you suggested and it still didn't work. The error stack still points at the ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class); line

Comment: What about running the Application: ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(App.class, args) ?